# Pass article ID with the uploaded file

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I am using the jquery uploader from here.

This is my button:

```
<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>إضافة صورة</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" accept="image/png" name="files[]">
</span>
<br>
<small>الحد الأقصى لحجم الملف هو 2.5 ميجابايت</small><br>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle">
<!-- The global progress bar -->
<div id="progress" class="progress" style="width: 300px">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
```

and this is my jquery:

```
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'jqueryupload/server/php/articlemedia/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        maxFileSize: 2500000,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                // $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                console.log("file", file.url) // see what this shows.
                $("#imgLogo").attr("src", file.url);
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
           window.location = '<?php echo $_SESSION["volow_domain_name"]; ?>memberarticlemedia?id=' + GetQueryStringValue('id');
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

I want to know how can I add a  then pass it to the UploadHandler.php so that I can process it there (add it to a database record)?

Thanks,
Jassim

Comment: Did you mean to say "I want to know how can I add *AN ID* then pass it to the UploadHandler.php"?

Comment: no. The ID is already there in the querystring. I am reading it already in the jquery as you can see. I want to pass that ID from the upload page to the UploadHandler.php then from there I'll take care of it.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is a FormData object. It's noted in [the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata).

Comment: I did tried. here is what I did I have added : <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>" ng-model="file.article_id"> in the html and in jquery I added           $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data)
        {
            $('#btnUploadIcon').prop('hidden', true);
            $('#btnUpload').prop('hidden', true);
            data.formData = {article_id: data.files[0].article_id};
        });     ---- what's next?